# How to implement a static menu bar in an UIPageviewcontroller?

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, menubar

im trying to build in a static menu bar in my uipageviewcontroller like youtube has. Does anyone know how to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking for is not part of the iOS SDK. As you will see the more you program, *there is not point in hacking the SDK here and there to make visual elements look and behave the way you want*. You're better off creating custom views in NIBs (or in code if so your heart desires), plugging the behavior you want into them, and use that instead of the SDK.

If you do want to use a UIPageViewController, here is a tutorial you can refer to for inspiration. The UISegmentControl can easily be replaced bya view of your own. Good luck!

**EDIT**: I realized I forgot how to include the link. Here you go: [Switching controllers with a UISegmentedControl](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/55-switching-view-controllers-with-uisegmentedcontrol)

Comment: Thanks for the response im going to creat a custom view programmatically ;)

Comment: @Kroplay99 Check out the link, it'll guide you well